# Arduino hex to string decoder not working

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-c++

I'm creating a HEX -> STR decoder using an LCD screen (display the HEX as well as the decoded values), a keypad (to input the HEX code), and a button (to press for it to decode the HEX values). The decoder works sometimes but sometimes it glitches out and presents unexpected values.

```
#include <Keypad.h>
#include<LiquidCrystal.h>

String hex; // store the hex values
String text; // store the decoded text
int calcButton = 0;

const byte ROWS = 4; 
const byte COLS = 4; 

char hexaKeys[ROWS][COLS] = {
  {'1', '2', '3', 'F'},
  {'4', '5', '6', 'E'},
  {'7', '8', '9', 'D'},
  {'A', '0', 'B', 'C'}
};

byte rowPins[ROWS] = {9, 8, 7, 6}; 
byte colPins[COLS] = {13, 12, 11, 10}; 

Keypad customKeypad = Keypad(makeKeymap(hexaKeys), rowPins, colPins, ROWS, COLS); 
LiquidCrystal lcd(5, 4, 3, 2, A0, A1);

char nibble2c(char c) {
   if ((c>='0') && (c<='9'))
      return c-'0' ;
   if ((c>='A') && (c<='F'))
      return c+10-'A' ;
   if ((c>='a') && (c<='a'))
      return c+10-'a' ;
   return -1 ;
}

char hex2c(char c1, char c2) {
   if(nibble2c(c2) >= 0)
     return nibble2c(c1)*16+nibble2c(c2) ;
   return nibble2c(c1) ;
}

// resets string values and clears screen
void erase() {
  hex = "";
  Serial.println(hex);
  text = "";
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.setCursor(0,0);
}

// decode the hex values
String calculate(String hex) {
  if (hex.length()%2 != 0) {
    lcd.setCursor(0,0);
    lcd.print("No of characters");
    lcd.setCursor(0,1);
    lcd.print("needs to be even");
    delay(2000);
    erase();
  }
  else {
    for (int i = 0; i < hex.length() - 1; i+=2){
      for (int j = 1; j < hex.length(); j+=2){
         text += hex2c(hex[i], hex[j]);
      }
    }
  }
}



void setup() {
  pinMode(A2, INPUT);
  lcd.begin(16, 2);
  lcd.setCursor(0,0);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  calcButton = digitalRead(A2); // decode button
  char customKey = customKeypad.getKey();

  // if keypad is pressed, add hex values to str
  if (customKey){
    lcd.print(customKey);
    hex += customKey;
    Serial.println(hex);
  }

  // if button is pressed, decode
  if (calcButton == 1) {
    lcd.clear();
    calculate(hex);
    hex = "";
    lcd.print(text);
    text = "";
    delay(1500);
    lcd.clear();
  }
}
```

I input `49` and get `I` (which is correct) but when I input `4949` I expect the output to be `II` but it outputs `IIII` and when I input `6F` expecting `o` the entire screen blurs and glitches.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
for (int i = 0; i < hex.length() - 1; i+=2){
  for (int j = 1; j < hex.length(); j+=2){
     text += hex2c(hex[i], hex[j]);
  }
}
```

Notice that you iterate over the hex string `length()*length()/4` times, combining every even hex character from the string with *every* odd character in the string, not just the one immediately following it. For two-digit hexadecimal strings this works because there only is one odd- and one even-indexed character; for longer strings you get wrong results.

`4949` will combine `4` (#0) and `9` (#1), then `4` (#0) and `9` (#3) (wrong!), then `4` (#2) and `9` (#1) (wrong!), then `4` (#2) and `9` (#3), which gives you the result that `49494949` should give instead of `4949`.

What you want is just:

```
for (int i = 0; i < hex.length() - 1; i+=2){
  text += hex2c(hex[i], hex[i+1]);
}
```